# Correct way of determining r2 between two rasters in R

Tags: r, raster, tiff

I am trying to find the r2 between two rasters. For instance I have two rasters r1 and r2, which code caluclates the r2?

```
cor(values(r1), values(r2), use="complete.obs", method = 'pearson')
```

or

stacking the rasters and converting it into dataframe and finding the r2.

```
stack1 <- stack(r1, r2)
df1 <- data.frame(na.omit(values(stack1)))
head(df1)
valueofdf1 = lm(gc ~ vc, data=df1)
summary(valueofdf1)$r.squared
```

Both procedures give a different r2. Thats why I am confused. I donot want to find a correlation but i would like to find a value of r2 between two rasters.

Comment: R2 is the proportion of the variance in the dependent variable that is predictable from the independent variable. With little experience in rasters, could you elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish by calculating this? What I _can_ answer, is that `cor()` does not give you the R2, but R. What values are you getting?

Comment: Correlation between X and Y and R2 of a regression between X and Y are two separate measures, but there is a strong link between the two. See e.g. https://win-vector.com/2011/11/21/correlation-and-r-squared/

Comment: @mhh For r2 I am getting a value of 0.35 and for r correlation the value is 0.59

Comment: @HallieSheikh, then you are getting numbers as expected. R2 = r * r. Thus, 0.59 * 0.59 ~= 0.35
Like I said, `cor` returns the correlation (r). Raise it to the power of 2 to get R2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first, `cor` does not return R^2, but R.
As stated in the comments, you are getting the expected output, as R2 = R*R.

As such, both of these methods are interchangeable (for all practical reasons), as long as you do the necessary adjustments.